# import data from csv to mysql using cakephp 2.7.5

Tags: cakephp

I have csv file. and i have already uploaded now i want put its data into my database in cakephp 2.7.5

csv file contain field name exactly same as employee table field name 
my question is how to put data in employee table
here function code

public function import_csv(){

```
    $this->loadModel('Csvimport');    

    if ($this->request->is('post', 'put')) {

        $this->request->data['Csvimport']['created_user_id']    = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->request->data['Csvimport']['modified_user_id']   = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

            $file = $this->request->data['Csvimport']['file_name'];

                $name = explode(".", $file['name']);
                //echo "before:".$file['name'][$i];
                $name = uniqid().".".$name[1];
                //echo "after:".$name;

                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($name, '.')), 1); //get the extension
                $arr_ext = array('csv');  //set allowed extensions
                //only process if the extension is valid
            if ($file['size'] < 1000000) {

                if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext)){

                    //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
                    //where we are putting it

                    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . '/attachments/csvimports/' . $name);
                    //prepare the filename for database entry
                    $this->request->data['Csvimport']['file_name'] = $name;
                    $this->request->data['Csvimport']['file_type'] = $file['type'];
                    $this->request->data['Csvimport']['file_size'] = $file['size'];
                }else{
                    $message = 'Your File should be in given formats only.';
                    $this->set('message',$message);
                    $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'error_flesh', array(), 'error');

                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'csvimports' , 'action' => 'import_csv'));
                }
            }else{
                $message = 'Your File should be Upto 1MB only.';
                $this->set('message',$message);
                $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'error_flesh', array(), 'error');

                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'csvimports' , 'action' => 'import_csv'));
            }
        }
        $this->Csvimport->id = $id;
        if ($this->Csvimport->save($this->request->data)){  

            $message = 'The Csv File has been Uploaded';
            $this->set('message',$message);
            $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'success_flesh', array(), 'successfully');

            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'csvimports' , 'action' => 'import_csv'));
        } else {

            $message = 'The Csv File could not be Uploaded. Please, try again.';
            $this->set('message',$message);
            $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'error_flesh', array(), 'error');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use something like `PHPExcel` to load and iterate through the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to loop over every row of data before importing it, 
consider using

```
$this->Csvimport->create()
$this->Csvimport->save(['fieldName'=>$data1, 'fieldName'=>$data2, ... ]);
```

If you don't need that, then use saveAll on the whole array once you have it as such. 
here is cakes documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html